# How to pass a sort parameter to order?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I want to make it so that can choose by what value to sort.

Can't pass the parameter this way:

```
 order: {
     sort: order
 },
```

How do I do this?

```
const search = query.search || '';
const order = query.order || 'ASC';
const sort = query.sort || '';

const [data, total] = await this.userRepository.findAndCount({
    relations: ['role'],
    where: [{
        username: ILike(`%${search}%`),
        email: ILike(`%${search}%`)
    }],
    order: {
        sort: order
    },
    take,
    skip: (page - 1) * take
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is this:

```js
const [data, total] = await this.userRepository.findAndCount({
    ...
    order: {
        [sort]: order
    },
    ...
});
```

Although, I should warn you that this might throw you an exception when you have an empty string for `sort`.

Comment: Using spread syntax is possible to avoid exception when `sort` is an empty string (and more in general, a falsy value).  `...(sort && { [sort]: order })` will set `[sort]: order` only if `sort` is truthy